# Balsamiq for network or architecture diagrams

Tags: architecture, diagram, software-design

I love the sketchy look of Balsamiq and the ability to put designs together quickly. I would love to be able to do the same thing for architecture diagrams but Balsamiq doesn't have any objects for those kinds of drawings.

Visio and PowerPoint work OK, but the interface gets in the way. (searching for objects, etc.) The end result is also too polished and formal looking, which is bad at the conceptual stage of a new system.

Is there another tool that works like Balsamiq that would work for architecture diagrams? Whiteboard + camera is good, but I don't always have a whiteboard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Balsamiq's CEO has received this request often, and pushed back at first because he didn't want to dilute the focus of the tool. It appears he may be changing his mind, as the request is getting a lot of user support and is now [marked as "under consideration"](http://community.balsamiq.com/balsamiq/topics/balsamiq_for_software_architects).

A member of the Balsamiq community named Michael created a set of [network diagram shapes](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/diagrams/Network+Diagrams). If you're interested in installing them, [follow these directions](https://mockupstogo.mybalsamiq.com/projects/aboutmtg/Finding+and+Using+Libraries).

I downloaded the shapes and set up my Balsamiq assets in a Dropbox folder which gives me access to them from any computer I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac - what about Diagrammix?

[link on itunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/diagrammix/id418534796?mt=12)